# Sleepless Mac although disabled PowerNap

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, power-nap

I have got a late 2012 Mac Mini.
I like that, when I put my mac to sleep, it sleeps but, my Mac, since I bought it, even if I put in sleep mode it keep working.

For example tonight I heard it working while I was sleeping (Mac is 1,5m from my pillow!) and this morning, looking at the console, it keep doing

```
29/10/15 06:29:21,285 secd[332]:  SOSEngineCreateMessage_locked 0tO+TZaAgGvPu3zt06Cf+Hoxvo:xvJCfnGe/EQhMHiLAfw7g6Yo9H error in send: Error Domain=com.apple.security.sos.error Code=1032 "peer: dpTJSdz3zg6x6mbOpQZb5DX0Hx not found" UserInfo={NSDescription=peer: dpTJSdz3zg6x6mbOpQZb5DX0Hx not found}
29/10/15 06:29:21,286 secd[332]:  SOSEngineCreateMessage_locked 0tO+TZaAgGvPu3zt06Cf+Hoxvo:0FMuFyL3Yys/PPBGTitpl03kvm error in send: Error Domain=com.apple.security.sos.error Code=1032 "peer: dpTJSdz3zg6x6mbOpQZb5DX0Hx not found" UserInfo={NSDescription=peer: dpTJSdz3zg6x6mbOpQZb5DX0Hx not found}
29/10/15 06:29:21,296 secd[332]:  SOSEngineCreateMessage_locked 0tO+TZaAgGvPu3zt06Cf+Hoxvo:eF41woRcEPyTixrXTfYoNNOsKv error in send: Error Domain=com.apple.security.sos.error Code=1032 "peer: dpTJSdz3zg6x6mbOpQZb5DX0Hx not found" UserInfo={NSDescription=peer: dpTJSdz3zg6x6mbOpQZb5DX0Hx not found}
29/10/15 06:29:21,299 secd[332]:  SOSEngineCreateMessage_locked 0tO+TZaAgGvPu3zt06Cf+Hoxvo:CZlGqQrp/9K9fhZ2TgH6qtffzQ error in send: Error Domain=com.apple.security.sos.error Code=1032 "peer: dpTJSdz3zg6x6mbOpQZb5DX0Hx not found" UserInfo={NSDescription=peer: dpTJSdz3zg6x6mbOpQZb5DX0Hx not found}
29/10/15 06:29:21,300 secd[332]:  SOSEngineCreateMessage_locked 0tO+TZaAgGvPu3zt06Cf+Hoxvo:by7oZw3Sw4DkHN7ijdFdsqVbeg error in send: Error Domain=com.apple.security.sos.error Code=1032 "peer: dpTJSdz3zg6x6mbOpQZb5DX0Hx not found" UserInfo={NSDescription=peer: dpTJSdz3zg6x6mbOpQZb5DX0Hx not found}
29/10/15 06:29:21,300 secd[332]:  __SOSCCProcessSyncWithAllPeers_Server_block_invoke sync with all peers failed: Error Domain=com.apple.security.sos.error Code=1032 "peer: dpTJSdz3zg6x6mbOpQZb5DX0Hx not found" UserInfo={NSDescription=peer: dpTJSdz3zg6x6mbOpQZb5DX0Hx not found}
29/10/15 06:29:21,356 CloudKeychainProxy[341]:  __39-[UbiqitousKVSProxy doSyncWithAllPeers]_block_invoke_2 <UBK-s-pC---> syncWithAllPeers (null), rescheduling timer
29/10/15 06:29:36,622 secd[332]:  SOSEngineCreateMessage_locked 0tO+TZaAgGvPu3zt06Cf+Hoxvo:xvJCfnGe/EQhMHiLAfw7g6Yo9H error in send: Error Domain=com.apple.security.sos.error Code=1032 "peer: dpTJSdz3zg6x6mbOpQZb5DX0Hx not found" UserInfo={NSDescription=peer: dpTJSdz3zg6x6mbOpQZb5DX0Hx not found}
29/10/15 06:29:36,624 secd[332]:  SOSEngineCreateMessage_locked 0tO+TZaAgGvPu3zt06Cf+Hoxvo:0FMuFyL3Yys/PPBGTitpl03kvm error in send: Error Domain=com.apple.security.sos.error Code=1032 "peer: dpTJSdz3zg6x6mbOpQZb5DX0Hx not found" UserInfo={NSDescription=peer: dpTJSdz3zg6x6mbOpQZb5DX0Hx not found}
29/10/15 06:29:36,634 secd[332]:  SOSEngineCreateMessage_locked 0tO+TZaAgGvPu3zt06Cf+Hoxvo:eF41woRcEPyTixrXTfYoNNOsKv error in send: Error Domain=com.apple.security.sos.error Code=1032 "peer: dpTJSdz3zg6x6mbOpQZb5DX0Hx not found" UserInfo={NSDescription=peer: dpTJSdz3zg6x6mbOpQZb5DX0Hx not found}
29/10/15 06:29:36,637 secd[332]:  SOSEngineCreateMessage_locked 0tO+TZaAgGvPu3zt06Cf+Hoxvo:CZlGqQrp/9K9fhZ2TgH6qtffzQ error in send: Error Domain=com.apple.security.sos.error Code=1032 "peer: dpTJSdz3zg6x6mbOpQZb5DX0Hx not found" UserInfo={NSDescription=peer: dpTJSdz3zg6x6mbOpQZb5DX0Hx not found}
29/10/15 06:29:36,638 secd[332]:  SOSEngineCreateMessage_locked 0tO+TZaAgGvPu3zt06Cf+Hoxvo:by7oZw3Sw4DkHN7ijdFdsqVbeg error in send: Error Domain=com.apple.security.sos.error Code=1032 "peer: dpTJSdz3zg6x6mbOpQZb5DX0Hx not found" UserInfo={NSDescription=peer: dpTJSdz3zg6x6mbOpQZb5DX0Hx not found}
29/10/15 06:29:36,639 secd[332]:  __SOSCCProcessSyncWithAllPeers_Server_block_invoke sync with all peers failed: Error Domain=com.apple.security.sos.error Code=1032 "peer: dpTJSdz3zg6x6mbOpQZb5DX0Hx not found" UserInfo={NSDescription=peer: dpTJSdz3zg6x6mbOpQZb5DX0Hx not found}
29/10/15 06:29:36,673 CloudKeychainProxy[341]:  __39-[UbiqitousKVSProxy doSyncWithAllPeers]_block_invoke_2 <UBK-s-pC---> syncWithAllPeers (null), rescheduling timer
```

all night long.
I tried disabling PowerNap but that the result!

Is there a way to put Mac really in standby mode? (turning it off is not standby!!)

Comment: I am having the same issue on El Capitan.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something else on your network is pinging it, causing it to wake up. Does turning off "Wake for Wi-Fi network access" in Energy Saver preferences help (if it was on already)?

[image: Wake for Network Access screenshot]

Comment: Nope, it's already disabled...

Comment: Hm, I don't know then. Are you sleeping it manually, or just letting it go to sleep automatically?

Comment: Most of times manually.

Answer (score -2):

It might be due to the new "Power Nap" feature that allows your Mac to check a few things while asleep. To disable this for while you're on battery and/or adapter power head to System Preferences > Energy Saver.

Comment: Did you read the title or the body of my question?!